# How to iterate all input folders (containing coverages) using Python with ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: python, shapefile, convert, arcgis-9.3, batch

I'm trying to write python scripts to batch convert thousands of coverages to shapefiles in arcgis 9.3. The coverages files are in different folders:

```
d:/area_A/building
d:/area_B/building
d:/area_C/building
...
```

and the output file will be merged or unioned into a single shapefile:

```
d:/output/building_merged.shp
```

I'm stuck in iterating all the input folders..here is what I've got so far:

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

try:    
    gp.Workspace = "d:/area_A/building"   
    gp.FeatureClassToShapefile("polygon","d:/output")  
except:     
    print gp.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 2):

You say "I'm stuck in iterating all the input folders" so that is the Question this Answer addresses.

Iterating through ArcGIS workspaces becomes **[much easier at ArcGIS 10.1 SP1](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/inventorying-data-a-new-approach/)** using arcpy.da.Walk.

However, it could be done using earlier versions of arcpy and arcgisscripting using os.walk as described **[here](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/recursive-list-feature-classes/)** or glob and other techniques as described **[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48537/how-to-make-a-gis-inventory)**.