# How can I export a list of an mxd's content (layers names) into a table or a pdf?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, export, mxd

I am using Arcgis 10.2.

I have created a set of mxd from which I need a list of the layers and their characteristics (Name, sources, symbologie - maybe as in legend, if there is an Definiton Query, and other representational aspects). I would like this list to be in a table or a Report or something simple to read/understand.

I need this in order to inform the colleagues what data they have to work, how and why in order to simplify the integration in the mxd templates.

This seems like a Report Job but I couldn't figure out why it was not doing what I needed. This sounds such a Basic Task that there must be a tool somewhere?

Have any of you seen some tools doing that type of export?

I hope that made sense. Will definitely clarify as much as needed.

Many thanks

EDIT: See Alex' reply

Comment: Thank Alex, now, hum, how do I use this? or where do I paste the code? Sorry, real stupid at developing...

Comment: If you right click on the mxd in catalog and go to *set data sources* you get a list of the feature classes.. I'm slightly confident you can copy and paste into notepad from this interface. Wouldn't like to do this for a lot of them though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A software that would help you with providing the inventory information of your map documents is called [X-Ray for ArcMap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f0ae73e90c1a4992a1059e7d370966d4). It is delivered as an [ArcGIS add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/) without the source code (so you cannot make any modifications and can use this piece of software as-is only).

X-Ray for ArcMap will help you develop and refine map documents by:

```
Documenting the layer and their properties contained in each map document
Documenting the source of each layer in a map document
Documenting label properties for each layer in a map document
Analyzing the differences between two map documents
Synchronizing layer aliases with changes made to field aliases in the source (GDB) 
Localizing layer names and descriptions in your map document
Editing the layer properties in a simple spreadsheet
```

Watch the [video](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1498/introduction-to-x_dash_ray-for-arcmap) on how get started.

In case you require a custom solution that would have certain functions that ArcMap X-ray is missing, consider using Python with arcpy site package. There is a good sample [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34797/14435) which you can get started with to modify to meet your needs. Another post generally related is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48537/how-to-make-a-gis-inventory).

Comment: Alex, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!