# How do I automatically generate a spatial data catalogue from shape files and .gdbs?

Tags: qgis, postgis, data, metadata, open-source-gis

I've recently inherited a whole bunch of spatial data (mostly shapefiles but some .gdbs) which relate to a bunch of different cities. I'm looking for a way to take an inventory of what data I've got for each city, preferably automated!

Does anyone know of any (free) tools that would allow me for example, to create a catalogue of my data (and metadata) from the files contained within my directory structure?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and tend to use QGIS/PostGIS.

Comment: What kind of metadata?

Comment: @NathanW, just basic descriptive stuff - file name, spatial extent, CRS projection etc. I really just want a comprehensive list/register of everything in a bunch of folders

Comment: [How to make a GIS inventory?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48537) is a closely-related question. Although it has an ArcGIS leaning, there is a pure Python answer that might help you get started. Since this is a fairly common use case, I might suggest we merge the two questions, allowing both FOSS and commercial solutions.