# Add metadata to dataset (feature class, coverage or shapefile) from a .csv using arcpy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, metadata, import

I am looking for a script that will take metadata information provided in an excel table, convert it to a .csv and import the values to populate some of the dataset's ArcGIS metadata elements.

I came across this post today and it is essentially the reverse of what I need (it grabs metadata elements and exports them to a .csv) and thought it might help:

[Creating a table containing all filenames (and possibly metadata) in a File Geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34729/creating-a-table-containing-all-filenames-and-possibly-metadata-in-a-file-geod)

I am a novice programmer (with some python under my belt) and am new to this site.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using? Also, what metadata standard are you interested in?

Comment: Here's a [one-off](https://github.com/chadcooper/metacopyr/blob/master/metacopyr.py) I did for someone, maybe it could help in conjunction with the [Import Metadata Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000000w000000).