# Listing all feature datasets and classes from multiple geodatabase into CSV file?

Tags: python, arcpy, feature-class, feature-dataset

I have a folder having multiple geodatabase and I am calling that folder “Multiplegdb”
There are 3 geodatabase in a folder which are as follows:

- ABC.gdb
- UVW.gdb
- XYZ.gdb

Each geodatabase have several ‘Feature Dataset’ and each ‘Feature dataset’ have several ‘Feature Classes’.

My task:

I would like to list all the features datasets and feature classes in each geodatabase in a folder into CSV. I also would like to get the metadata information from each feature class into CSV file. The format of CSV file will be:
GDB Name, Feature Dataset Name, Feature Classes name, Summary, Descriptions, Credits, Date Modified, File path.

Comment: Some of those fields are not obtainable with arcpy.

Comment: I think you should investigate how to access that metadata information (Summary, Descriptions, Credits, etc) from ArcPy as a separate question.  I'm not certain that it can be read but I would hope it could.

Comment: A couple of similar questions & answers.  I think the first will answer your question, or the 2nd will at least answer part 1 of your question: [Creating table containing all filenames (and possibly metadata) in File Geodatabase?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34729/creating-table-containing-all-filenames-and-possibly-metadata-in-file-geodatab/34797#34797) or [Listing all feature classes in File Geodatabase, including within feature datasets?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase)

Comment: I've successfully exported metadata to XML and read it using arcpy in the past. The implementation at the linked questions is cleaner than mine, though :)

Answer (score 2):

If I were undertaking this task I would first break it into two "halves":

1. Reading geodatabases and printing results
2. Writing results to CSV

I think this question should focus on just the first of these, and within that start by writing a code snippet that uses ListWorkspaces, ListFeatureDatasets and ListFeatureClasses to print the name of every feature class, in every feature dataset, in every geodatabase, in a single folder.

Once that is working, if your geodatabases are not all in one folder then begin to write a code snippet that uses arcpy.da.Walk to walk through your folder structure looking for them.

Writing results to CSV is more of a StackOverflow (Python) rather than GIS Stack Exchange (ArcPy) question so while there may be snippets here to do that, if you do not find them, then the place to ask is StackOverflow.